# find Factorial of no. It is working fine but i am not able to understand why its giving me factorial 0 for no 56,89,77 and other some numbers

Tags: java, factorial

This is my code for factorial program. it is working fine but i am not able to understand why its giving me factorial 0 for no 56,89,77 and other some numbers.

```
private static void factorial() {
    int resultant = 1, i;
    System.out.println("Please Enter any number to find factorial : ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int fact = scan.nextInt();
    for (i = 1; i <= fact; i++) {
        resultant = resultant * i;
    }
    System.out.println("Factorial of number : " + resultant);
}
```

Comment: You're encountering integer overflow. If you replace `resultant = resultant * i` with `resultant = Math.multiplyExact(resultant, i)` you'll even get a `java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow`.

Comment: Use `BigInteger` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every even number that is part of the product contributes a trailing zero to the factorial. Actually to be more precise, the trailing zero count of a (unlimited precision) product is the sum of the trailing zero counts of the inputs. In finite precision the number of trailing zeroes is obviously limited by the size of the number.

So eventually, and this happens pretty quickly, the number of trailing zeroes becomes greater than or equal to 32, in which case *all* bits of an `int` would be zero. The same thing of course happens with `long`, a little later, at 64 trailing zeroes. And some time before that, even though the result is not totally zero yet, it would already have stopped matching what the result would have been in unlimited precision.

For example 34! in hexadecimal is

```
de1bc4d19efcac82445da75b00000000
```

The 8 least significant digits would be what you would get if you computed it with 32 bit integers, and all those digits are zero.

Answer (score 1):

You should  know the size of `int` is fixed to 32 bits. When ever your computation results in producing a large number that cannot fit into those 32 bits, some bits will get overflowed producing a wrong result. You can try with this code.

```
private static void factorial() {
    int resultant = 1, i;
    System.out.println("Please Enter any number to find factorial : ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int fact = scan.nextInt();
    for (i = 1; i <= fact; i++) {
        int test=resultant;
        resultant = resultant * i;
        if(resultant<test){
            system.out.println("Looks like overflow occured");
        }   
    }
    System.out.println("Factorial of number : " + resultant);
}
```

Better way will be to use `BigInteger` instead of `int`.

Comment: thank you so much for reminding. I just forgot about it while running my old programs.

Answer (score 0):

Factorial of such large numbers will be very large. You have to use a data type that can store very large numbers (we are talking about billions and trillions). BigInteger data type may work. Give it a try.